# View all data attached to an element using jQuery's .data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

If I've attached a number of key-value pairs to a DOM element using .data(), is there any way to iterate them so I can log them in the console?  Alternately, is there a way to view this data with a development tool like FireBug?  This would be really helpful when debugging a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) without any parameters, like this:

```
console.log($("selector").data());
```

It'll be logged as an object in the console easy to navigate.

Comment: @keithjgrant - Yup, use `$.cache` to see the data for all elements, if that helps any.